# How to extract part of filename in awk script

Tags: awk

I have following file which I am splitting into multiple files using awk script

Name of original File: `RTLOG_5019_05122016110959.DAT`

I want to set the name of split files as below:

```
RTLOG_5019_<timestmap (format: mmddyyyyhhmiss) >.DAT.
```

How do I achieve this? I don't want to hard-code the filename and also make `filename-RTLOG_5019_05122016110959.DAT` as parameter

Following is my awk script

```
awk -v stamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)  '
/^FHEAD/        {HD = $0  
             next
            }

/^THEAD/        {if (FN)  { printf "FTAIL%010d%010d" ORS, LN+2, LN > FN
                        close (FN)
                        LN = 0
                      }
             FN = "RTLOG_5019_" stamp ".DAT" ++f
             print HD > FN
            }

            !/^FTAIL/ {print >> FN
             LN++
            }

END             {printf "FTAIL%010d%010d" ORS, LN+2, LN > FN
            } ' RTLOG_5019_05122016110959.DAT
```

Comment: A bit unrelated, but I'd highly suggest using yymmdd instead of ddmmyy in any filename that contains a date because it will make it possible to browse the files in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, exactly, but this might help:

```
 awk -v var="new" 'BEGIN { print substr(ARGV[1], 0, 2) var substr(ARGV[1], 6); }' myoldfilename
```

Comment: Actually , I want to set the filename as RTLOG_5019_timestamp where RTLOG_5019 is derived from filename RTLOG_5019_05122016110959.DAT

Comment: So, something like `awk -v var="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)" 'BEGIN { print substr(ARGV[1], 0, 10) var; }'  RTLOG_5019_05122016110959.DAT`